# TensorFlow sess.run(init) expects a feed_dict

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to make a simple multilayer perceptron with one hidden layer using tensorflow. When I try to run the initializer, I get an error that it expected a `feed_dict` with a placeholder. Usually I don't have to feed anything into `sess.run(init)`
Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ins = int(input('number of inputs: '))
hiddens = int(input('number of hiddens: '))
outs = int(input('number of outs: '))

learning_rate = .01

x_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,ins],name='inputs_placeholder')
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,outs],name='outputs_placeholder')

W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([ins,hiddens],-.5,.5),name='weights_to_hidden')
B1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([hiddens],-.5,.5),name='bias_to_hidden')
z = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x_,W1) + B1)

W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([hiddens,outs],-.5,.5),name='weights_to_out')
B2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([outs],-.5,.5),name='bias_to_out')
y = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(z,W2) + B2)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(( (y_ * tf.log(y)) + ((1 - y_) * tf.log(1.0 - y)) ) * -1)
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
```

I input 2, 2, then 1 for the inputs, hiddens, and outputs. When I run it, i get this:

```
 InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'inputs_placeholder_1' with dtype float
     [[Node: inputs_placeholder_1 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

Why is it requiring a feed_dict and why does it think there is an `'inputs_placeholder_1'` placeholder?

Comment: [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwFQMMG-6EoRajFkNlVqdm9kMDA/view?usp=sharing) is a link to the actual jupyter notebook I ran it in

Comment: Replaying the snippet you've provided above, I'm unable to reproduce the error. Do you see it in a clean python shell/jupyter notebook? (Wondering if it's possible that there were previous commands in your notebook that were at play here)

Comment: Your notebook runs fine on my side, so as @ash suggested there's likely some stale state left.

Comment: Yes, that's what it was. I just had to restart the kernel.